# How do I access the request body in XML format in a WCF REST service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I can create a WCF REST service and POST, PUT and GET data OK.

How do I access the request body in XML format on the service side to send to an SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass arguments to to your web methods using this attribute

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "users/{username}")]
```

here is a sample method from [msdn](http://goo.gl/6uMMe)

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "users/{username}")]
[OperationContract]
User GetUserAccount(string username)
{
    if (!IsUserAuthorized(username))
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode =
            HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return;
    }
    User user = FindUser(username);
    if (user == null)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetStatusAsNotFound();
        return null;
    }
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. forgot to add the request body is an xml document. so i need to have that document saved to sql once postd to service

Comment: RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml property of webinvoke should help you.eg: [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: i'm still having trouble getting the body into a dataset. do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC3, the Request object is available in the controller, with the content of the body being available in the InputStream object. This code worked for me:

```
        this.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        var xmlContent = new System.IO.StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Hope that helps.